# MySQL "chain" multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i got a simple (noob) question:

My Database has 2 tables: Delivery and Inventory.

I want to use a PHP function to insert a name to the delivery table and a product to the inventory.

How can i "chain" queries? Or can I do both in only one query? When i add both queries in the function, it stops inserting after the first insert.

Thanks in advance.

`private $db`;

```
public function __construct()
   {


  $this->db = new mysqli("xx","xx","xx");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    die("error while connection to database!:".mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $this->db->select_db("xxx");

  if($this->db->errno)
  {
    die ($this->db->error);
  }


}
   public function addInfo($data)



{



$stmt = "INSERT INTO delivery ( 

   name

   ) VALUES (
   '".$data['name']."'
   );";

   $stmt2 = "INSERT INTO inventory ( 
   item

   ) VALUES (
   '".$data['item']."'
   );";

   //commit db request
   $result = $this->db->query($stmt);
   $result2 = $this->db->query($stmt2);

   if($result || result2 == 1)
   {
       return "succesfully inserted.";
   }

   return "your statment: ".$stmt."<br /> received result:".$result;
   }
```

Comment: Please add your table structure and what queries you've tried.

Comment: Add the code you are asking about. If you are using the `multi-query` function you can execute multiple queries with 1 call.

Comment: Sounds like you have a `return` after the first query. But we can't know, since we don't see your code.

Comment: information added